# Проверить на null ключи массива объекта ключей с уникальными именами react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть такой хук с массивом, в котором есть перечень ключей с уникальными именами. И каждый ключ содержит в себе массив с объектом:

```
const [Value, setValue] = useState([
      {
        Item1: [{test1: null, test2: null}],
        Item2: [{test1: "some text", test2: "some text"}],
        Item3: [{test1: null, test2: null}],
        ...
        ItemN: [{test1: null, test2: null}]
      }
])
```

Ключи `test1` и `test2` имена постоянные. Т.е. все `Item` будут содержать только эти ключи.
На деле, этим ключей `Item` будет очень много, и мне нужно проверить `test1` и `test2` на `null` каждого `Item`. Проблема с обращением к ключам `Item`.

Я пробовал `Object.keys`, но ничего не получаю, и ошибок так же нет:

```
{Object.keys(Value).map((item, i) => {
  if (item.test1 !== null && item.test2 !== null) {
     return (<div key={i}>{item.test1 - item.test2}</div>)
  }
})}
```

Comment: Откройте для себя чудо - `console.log()` Это очень тайные знания javaScript разработчиков! Внутрь можно вставить любую переменную и посмотреть, а что же там в ней сейчас лежит.

Comment: знаю об этом, спасибо

Comment: Ну а по существу, вместо `Object.keys` сделайте `Object.values` и должно заработать. И еще, вам надо всегда возвращать что то в методе map, иначе элемент станет `undefined`, если только это не является желаемым поведением

Comment: У вас в Item1 лежит массив с одним элементом - объект. Это так задумано? не проще положить просто объект? Если переделаете на `Object.values` то заработает сразу, если оставите, то `if (item[0].test1 !== null && item[0].test2 !== null)`

Comment: @SwaD да, вы правы. объект положить без массива проще

Comment: @SwaD, но все равно. даже с `Object.values` не перебирает `Value` на Item-ы.  Вывожу `console.log(item)` внутри условия `(item[0].test1 !== null && item[0].test2 !== null)`, и получаю все ключи `Item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если взять ваш формат стейта, а это у вас массив из 1 элемента, где лежит объект с ключами, значение каждого ключа это массив с объектом(arr-obj-arr-obj), тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```js
const Value =  [{
        Item1: [{test1: null, test2: null}],
        Item2: [{test1: "some text", test2: "some text"}],
        Item3: [{test1: null, test2: null}],
        ItemN: [{test1: null, test2: null}]
      }];
// получаем значения из 1го элемента массива
const res = Object.values(Value[0]).map((item, i) => {
  // проверяем в 1м элементе массива ключи
  if (item[0].test1 !== null && item[0].test2 !== null) {
     return 1;
  }
  return 0
})

console.log(res)
```

Хотя мне кажется, что массивы тут лишние и от них можно избавится, тогда стейт и код проверки будут выглядеть так:

```js
const Value =  {
        Item1: {test1: null, test2: null},
        Item2: {test1: "some text", test2: "some text"},
        Item3: {test1: null, test2: null},
        ItemN: {test1: null, test2: null}
      };

const res = Object.values(Value).map((item, i) => {
  if (item.test1 !== null && item.test2 !== null) {
     return 1;
  }
  return 0
})

console.log(res)
```

Чуть позже в снипет оберну и в порядок приведу. С телефона не удобно (

Comment: Согласен на счет лишних массивов. Вложил объект в ключ. Но у меня заработало только так: `Object.values(Value[0]).map((item, i) => { if (item.test1 !== null && item.test2 !== null) { ...` Спасибо огромное!

Comment: на самом деле мне нужно было просто указать массив для `Value` вот так `Value[0]` и `Object.values`. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @rabbit у вас ваш объект с itemами обернут в массив, поэтому и требуется [0], что бы обратиться к первому элементу. Уберите это, как во втором примере

Comment: я именно так и сделал.

Comment: сделал для вас два скриншота реального примера (позже удалю). вот так заработало

Comment: @rabbit смотрете первый вариант, там с [0] и второй, где без [0]. Сравните 2 обьекта между собой. Первый, это массив с объектами ключами, второй это объект с ключами. Рекомендую убрать массив, если добавлять элементы не планируете

Comment: @rabbit ну да, у вас там массив `useState([` вот тут  `[` это, условно начало массива... конец `])` уберете `[]` и будет просто объект и тогда [0] не нужно будет

Comment: убрал, и получаю ошибку `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: все, исправил это